# Using fineuploader, how can I use a HTTPS endpoint?

Tags: web-services, https, fine-uploader

I am relatively new to javascript, and I got an uploader tool called fineuploader that I was considering to use. However locally (development machine) I got it to work (vb.net), but when I put it on my external server, I noticed that there is a post done in http and directly to the server's domain name (e/g/ mydomain.com), instead of mydomain.com/testproject. The site only allows for https traffic.

Is there an easy way to change this? (so it should point at https://mydomain.com/testproject/FileUpload.aspx

The code used by fineuploader shows a parameter called 'endpoint: '/FileUpload.aspx'

Do I have to make changes in the settings of IIS for this webservice?

Comment: I think you have a cross-domain problem , as ajax does not allows you to post some data cross domain. Check this article for cross-domain posting :http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

Answer (score 0):

If you need to enable CORS (cross-domain requests), Fine Uploader supports this.  You should read [my blog post](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/31/cors-support-in-3-3/) on how CORS support is implemented in Fine Uploader and how you can support such requests in your server-side code.